# How to check if a Hive table exists using PySpark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to check if a table `schemaname.tablename` exists in Hive using `pysparkSQL`.

There is an option in Scala `spark.catalog.tableExists("schemaname.tablename")`.However , same functionality not available through `pySpark` .

Looking for a quick and clean approach to check if Hive table exists using `PySpark`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pyspark.sql.catalog` module is included from [spark >= 2.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/catalog.html)

If you are using ***spark < 2.3.0*** the you can use like below:

```
spark._jsparkSession.catalog().tableExists("schema.table")
True

spark._jsparkSession.catalog().tableExists("schema.table_false")
False
```

**or**

```
spark.catalog._jcatalog.tableExists("schema.table")
True
```

Comment: There is a better way now see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 7):

In PySpark it can be done as follows:

```
spark.catalog._jcatalog.tableExists("schemaname.tablename")
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are some more options. First let's create some random table from an arbitrary df with `df.write.saveAsTable("your_table")`.

**Option 1 - Spark >= 2.0**

Using `spark.catalog.listTables` i.e:

```py
"your_table" in [t.name for t in spark.catalog.listTables("default")] == True
```

**Option 2 - Spark >= 1.3**

Using `sqlContext.tableNames` i.e:

```py
"your_table" in sqlContext.tableNames("default") == True
```

**Option 3**

Using `spark.sql` i.e:

```py
spark.sql("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'your_table'").count() == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to  if a table schemaname.tablename exists in Hive using pyspark after 3.3.0 is `spark.catalog.tableExists("schemaname.tablename")` its better to not use the hidden method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic function to do the same:

```
def tableExists(tableName,schemaName='default'):
    return spark.sql(f"show tables in {schemaName} like '{tableName}'").count() == 1
```